# After adding mmenu the complete mmenu is not readable even tab navigation is not going to it, so its completely not clickable

Tags: mmenu

here is my code snippet, the mmenu is rendering on page but i can't able to click on any menu items, any suggestions pls

```
const menuElement = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menu = new Mmenu(menuElement, {
"slidingSubmenus": true,
"offCanvas": {
"position": "left",
},
"theme": "light",
});

<nav id="mobile-menu">
      <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/work">Our work</a></li>
                <li>About us
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
                        <li>The team
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/about/team/management">Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/about/team/development">Development</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Services
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/services/design">Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/services/development">Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/services/marketing">Marketing</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
</nav>
```

at last the menu is rendring but its nnot clickable, any idea why ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zz9QH.png)